# How to detect crop row using python OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am new to machine learning and image recognition. I did quite a lot of research and found that we can detect the line on python using Pattern Hough Transform. With all my research and implementation, I couldn't get to the correct solution.

Basically, I need to detect the crop rows, draw the line and get the coordinates of the lines as shown on the image. Can anyone please help me with the code?

This is the raw image 
[image]

This is how I want to process the image
[image]

This did not detect the correct pattern:

```
#import dependencies
import cv2
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#load image using cv's imread(nameoffile)
img = cv2.imread('crop.png')

#split the image into blue, green, and red channels
b,g,r = cv2.split(img) 
#here we 'amplify' the color green to stand out, without red/blue
gscale = 2*g-r-b #we are going to refer to this as our grayscale img
#Canny edge detection 
gscale = cv2.Canny(gscale,400,400,apertureSize = 3)
#checking the results (good practice)
plt.figure()
plt.plot(), plt.imshow(gscale)
plt.title('Canny Edge-Detection Results')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()

size = np.size(gscale) #returns the product of the array dimensions
skel = np.zeros(gscale.shape,np.uint8) #array of zeros
ret,gscale = cv2.threshold(gscale,128,255,0) #thresholding the image
element = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_CROSS,(3,3))
done = False
while( not done):
    eroded = cv2.erode(gscale,element)
    temp = cv2.dilate(eroded,element)
    temp = cv2.subtract(gscale,temp)
    skel = cv2.bitwise_or(skel,temp)
    gscale = eroded.copy()
    zeros = size - cv2.countNonZero(gscale)
    if zeros==size:
        done = True


lines = cv2.HoughLines(skel,1,np.pi/180,130)
a,b,c = lines.shape
for i in range(a):
    rho = lines[i][0][0]
    theta = lines[i][0][1]    
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(img,(x1,y1),(x2,y2),(0,0,255),2, cv2.LINE_AA)
#showing the results:
plt.subplot(121)
#OpenCV reads images as BGR, this corrects so it is displayed as RGB
plt.plot(),plt.imshow(cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)) 
plt.title('Row Detection'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.subplot(122)
plt.plot(),plt.imshow(skel,cmap='gray')
plt.title('Skeletal Image'), plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Your question is "do I really need to build a machine learning model?", but you show code saying it is not working as intended, which makes me believe you actually want help with that code. But you don't state this explicitly. If you want to get good, useful help here, you should make your question as concise and direct and explicit as possible. When people start guessing at what you want, things go sour pretty quickly. Please see [tour] and read [ask]. Thanks!

Comment: Of course, my answer to your explicit question is "no". Stuff that can be modelled doesn't need thousands of training images.

Comment: maybe you can adapt lane detection algorithms like in http://bakeaselfdrivingcar.blogspot.com/2017/11/project-3-advanced-lane-detection.html

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo. I updated the question.

Comment: Thanks @Micka will check that out

Comment: I think this is more a question for https://datascience.stackexchange.com, but you need definitely more informations about your data and scope.